# How to micro infestors most effectively

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg

I've been trying to get better with infestor usage. If I have just a couple of infestors, I seem to be able to use them OK against marine balls with a double-fungal. When I start getting 5+ infestors and trying to use them with zergling/roach to take on protoss balls/terran mech thor/hellion/tank compositions I am running into problems.

I normally have my lings/roaches on 1/2 and infestors on 3. I try to engage with lings/roaches and then tell the infestors to fungal, but with the delay from individual infestors moving into range and casting, the fungal doesn't always land on the targeted units.

Another problem is I frequently in the heat of battle end up mis-selecting and instead of my 3-f-click-f-click-f-click casting three fungals, I select some other unit by mistake and then my infestors proceed to mill around and die.

Before the neural parasite range nerf, I found it easy and effective vs void rays, tanks, colossuses etc. With the new short range I cannot seem to find a use for it. Any advice?

Finally with infested terrans it can be hard to spawn large numbers of eggs quickly, resulting in infestors being killed with high energy. I tired right clicking then shift+t queuing up large numbers, but then the infestors all cluster in a huddle trying to move into the "firing" position one at a time resulting in a slow deployment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question. I would suggest microing the Infestors to stay in the middle of the pack, possibly selecting the infestors and using the fungals first. Then quickly selecting the other units. I would almost tell you to consider having them all selected (Roaches,Lings, and Infestors) and then fungal growth as your units are moving in. Otherwise you would require a high APM to move those groups almost simultaneously to engage the enemy.

Also, you don't need to keep selecing the control group again for multiple fungals you can simply F-Click, F-Click, and repeat. As for triple clicking that is simply something you need to work on.

If you can manage to have some Burrowed infestors behind the enemy as he is moving up (already seen the attack coming and assuming he doesn't have detection) have them on a control group and burrowed and let the enemy pass then pop up from behind and take the key units under your control.

And for Infested terrans, you can have those Infestors burrowed and spam the "T" button and left click on the map where you want it. You again, don't need to select the control group again and again and shift clicking will not help at all. Simply T-Click, T-Click, and repeat. Do this very fast to spew out terrans. If burrowed you can move without getting hit typically. Even if they have detection I have noticed they don't seem to target burrowed units until there are no other attacking units in range. So just T-Click very rapidly.

Edit: As a side note, I tested Dbemerlin's idea and it does work to right click (Move) all infestors to start getting into range.

Comment: Since your answer covers almost everything, just a small comment: I find it good to right-click all infestors in range before starting the fungals, that way the individual infestors spend less time walking into range and the fungals have a higher chance of hitting the intended targets.

Comment: What do you mean by right-clicking? Also, if all of them are selected then the nearest ones will do the fungal.

Comment: I think one problem I had is that the nearest ones would cast, then get in the way of the further ones who aren't in range when they were trying to cast. Right clicking them into range first might be a good plan!

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to use the shift key.  You don't need to spam the T button to barf out a lot of infested terrans.  Just one T and then hold shift and click as many times as you need.  I'm not in front of the game right now and can't remember whether I can start holding shift  before the first click or not.  I'm pretty sure the same thing will work with fungal as well if you need three or four fungals to cover a large area.

Just do a one-player game and play around with it a little.  A 5 minute investment in experimentation will make a world of difference rather than trying to figure it out in the heat of a ladder game.